# How to rank order dates in R

Tags: r, dplyr, window-functions

I have a dataframe for multiple products and different date ranges. I want to assign unique value to each date so that even if the starting dates are different for various products, I can group by the dates.

```
df

acc product date
a1  p1      d1
a1  p1      d2
a1  p1      d3
a1  p1      d4
a1  p2      d1
a1  p2      d2
a1  p2      d3
a1  p3      d3
a1  p3      d4
```

I want to arrange the dates so that there is a unique identifier each for d1, d2, d3 etc.

I used the following code to try this:

```
df <- df %>% group_by(acc, product) %>% mutate(t = row_number())

Output

df

acc product date  t   EXPECTED
a1  p1      d1    1   1
a1  p1      d2    2   2
a1  p1      d3    3   3
a1  p1      d4    4   4
a1  p2      d1    1   1
a1  p2      d2    2   2
a1  p2      d3    3   3
a1  p3      d3    1   3
a1  p3      d4    2   4
```

Any suggestions for this?

Comment: use `dplyr::dense_rank()`

Comment: `df$t <- match(df$date, unique(df$date))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `dplyr::dense_rank()`

```
df %>% mutate(new = dense_rank(date))
  acc product date new
1  a1      p1   d1   1
2  a1      p1   d2   2
3  a1      p1   d3   3
4  a1      p1   d4   4
5  a1      p2   d1   1
6  a1      p2   d2   2
7  a1      p2   d3   3
8  a1      p3   d3   3
9  a1      p3   d4   4
```

**If however, you want to restart ranks for each `acc` use `group_by` before the mutate statement.**

dput used

```
df <- structure(list(acc = c("a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", 
"a1", "a1"), product = c("p1", "p1", "p1", "p1", "p2", "p2", 
"p2", "p3", "p3"), date = c("d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d1", "d2", 
"d3", "d3", "d4")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L
))
```

Comment: So, the issue was grouping by. Leaves a lot to be desired for the dense_rank documentation.